# Training Neural Network using TensorFlow on Large Video Dataset for Human Activity Recognition

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, dataset, memory

I am working on a Human Activity Recognition on videos using deep learning and want to train my Neural Network (ConvLSTM & LRCN) on my custom dataset. The issue that I am facing is that my dataset is more than 50 GB and I don't have that much memory to load it into the memory directly(16 GB RAM and Nvidia P2000 with 5 GB VRAM). I read about the TensorFlow `flow_from_directory` which is used to effectively load the dataset, but my problem is that I would like to load multiple images for single label.

For example, a video might have $n$ number of frames in it and I extract the required frames from it for training my NN on it, for instance a 30 sec video of walking label might have 2000 frames and I want to get every 20th frames (20,40,60...2000).

Now, how do I deal with sequence of these frames while using TensorFlow `flow_from_directory`? I have 40 Videos of each label (40 Walking, 40 Running, 40 jogging and so on) how do I tell TensorFlow that these $n$ frames belong to this single video(such as walking label) and how do I send them at once to the model to train on it?

As far as I know, the default behavior of `flow_from_directory` is that if we have 4 folder (cat, dog, zebra and fish) it go to each folder and gets each photo from it and assign the label same as the label name. But in my case I have for instance 3 folders (Walking, Running and Jogging) and in each folder I have Nested folders (Walking Video 1, Walking Video 2 and so on) and in each folder there are n number of frames belonging to that video label. How do I deal with that?

Nested folders Structures

Bold represents a folder

**Walking** (**Walking Video 1** (n frames belong to video 1), **Walking Video 2** (n frames belong to video 2) and so on for all the walking videos)

**Running** (**Running Video 1** (n frames belong to video 1), **Running Video 2** (n frames belong to video 2) and so on for all the Running videos)

and so on for all the labels

Answer (score 1):

At an early stage, you don't have to use all the data, but rather build a first model with a reasonable amount of data (ex: 4Gb) for 3 reasons:
1- The learning time is much shorter, so you can apply a fast improvement loop.
2- The necessary hardware is more affordable.
3- It is easily expandable to 50Gb.

In addition to that, you can apply some preprocessing techniques to compress the data, lower definintion, or select the most meaningful scenes with good differentiability.

The scenes should also be comparable and have the same frequency and the same frame, so that your NN can easily find patterns at the correct time.

The frame rate could be lower: existing models can have good results with 15 fps or less. You could start with 15 fps to see if the results are correct, and increase or decrease it until reaching an optimal result.

Finally, once you master a model with a smaller dataset, you can extend it to 50Gb defining smaller batches and using RAM or hard disk memory. Otherwise, you can buy a better hardware or rent a super GPU in a cloud (cf. GCloud, AWS or Paperspace) for an affordable price.

Comment: can i train my model multiple time? i mean can i  train with  5gb and then train with next 5 gb until i reach 50 gb? this way the whole dataset wont load in the memory and i can train it on my pc, i wont need to buy any cloud services or buy new hardware

Comment: No, you can't because every new training will write on all the previous ones: the first training would be trained over 50 times, whereas the last one only one. But if you lower the definition or reduce the batch size, you could expect good results.

Comment: Okay sir, thank you for your assistance! I really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome Sharjeel! If the answer is eventually relevant, could you validate the answer?

Comment: it really doesn't answer the question which i was looking for.

Comment: Sorry to learn it. Could you please clarify why? Did you have bad results with a smaller sample and you couldn't extend it correctly?

Comment: I read on TensorFlow docs (Correct me if I am wrong) that it is possible to retrain the model multiple times without losing the previous training weights. And also I need a way around to deal with the sequence of images in a videos. I cant load whole video dataset. I know about the image data generator but I works well with images which don't have any sequence. I want to make a data pipeline which can respect the sequence of the frames from a video and also load the dataset effectively in the memory. Can you please help me with that?

Comment: I recommend opening a new question: there might be other people who could help as well.

Comment: And check if you can train a model multiple times with new data. I'm surprised that there is no impact on weights. Generally speaking, you can train an existing model with just one (maybe a few) set of data, it's called fine-tuning. But I can't see why training on several new datasets won't impact weights. Weights are not selectively set.

Comment: No, the dataset is the same but I don't have that much memory on my workstation to train it at once. I was thinking if I could divide the dataset into subsets and then train my DL model on it. This way I wont have to deal with the pipeline and also can train my model on my own workstation other than subscribing to 3rd party cloud providers such a Google Colab.

Comment: And also I am not saying that retraining doesn't alter the weights, what I am saying is that we can train an already train model multiple times to improve it. And in my case train it multiple times on subsets of a dataset to avoid memory bottleneck.

Comment: I doubt that "training a model multiple times" means "training a model with 50 different datasets 50 times", but rather "training a model with a single new dataset a few times".
I might be wrong, but this is my opinion. Furthermore, the model should be big enough to cover such amount of data. A model adapted to 1 dataset over 50, cannot cover 50 datasets, don't you think?

Comment: Can you please refer to this for more clarification? ( https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/114812/how-to-make-a-pipeline-for-videos-dataset-for-tensorflow-sequence-matters-tr ) I asked the same question but I thing I will help you understand my query in better way

Comment: OK @SharjeelM. and does the previous information answer to your question? If yes, feel free to validate the answer.